# I couldn't update and upgrade my ubuntu installation

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

Every time I run `sudo apt-get update` I run into the following error

```
Err:1 http://repository.spotify. scomtable InRelease
  Could not resolve 'repository.spotify.'
Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/munin-plugins/ubuntu bionic InRelease 
Hit:3 http://et.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:4 http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable bionic InRelease  
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/dartsim/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease             
Get:5 http://et.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]   
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]    
Hit:9 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                           
Get:10 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease [3,182 B]  
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fcl-debs/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease           
Hit:12 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                  
Hit:13 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease               
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-3/ubuntu bionic InRelease     
Get:8 http://et.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB] 
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libccd-debs/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease        
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease        
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu bionic InRelease    
Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Hit:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thomas-schiex/blender/ubuntu bionic InRelease  
Hit:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease       
Err:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/munin-plugins/ubuntu bionic Release  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fcl-debs/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Get:16 https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/ubuntu bionic InRelease [23.2 kB]
Err:16 https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6B05F25D762E3157
Err:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-3/ubuntu bionic Release       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libccd-debs/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: Release file for https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode/dists/stable/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 4h 23min 41s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://et.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 4h 54min 3s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://et.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 3h 21min 25s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 3h 20min 40s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/munin-plugins/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/fcl-debs/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6B05F25D762E3157
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-3/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/libccd-debs/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

The problem still persists when running `sudo apt-get upgrade`. How can I avoid this?

Comment: You have an error in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list`. There it says `deb http://repository.spotify. scomtable` which should be `deb http://repository.spotify.com stable`. Further, you have several PPA's that don't provide a `bionic` version for their software.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  You can avoid error such as this by checking the PPA's support your release of Ubuntu. I picked one at random and looked (http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/munin-plugins/ubuntu/dists/)  and it supports Ubuntu 10.04.  Don't add PPA's that are no longer supported, and esp. don't support your release of Ubuntu.  You need to remove them.

Comment: @guiverc How do I remove those PPA's that are no longer supported

Comment: Refer to the duplicate notice - it contains information on how to remove.

Comment: @guiverc I mean the list of PPA's that are not supported by my version of Ubuntu Is there a `list` command?

Comment: I don't know of one, and can't imagine one being created. The ideal approach is to not-add PPA's that aren't supported, thus why would you write a script to remove what you won't add. PPA's are third-party sources that are 'vetted' only by you, so part of your vetting as to can they be trusted (so I trust the creator) would of course include were they made for your current system (and be maintained into the future). Good security mandates no-command is necessary.

Comment: @Jos throws an error `E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.` after editing  Spotify.list

Comment: In that case, put a `#` in front of it and do a regular update/upgrade. Later, inspect what's wrong with the line. I believe the text as stated in my previous comment is well-formed.

Comment: @SamuelMideksa Log into terminal as root with `root -i` then type `cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d`. PPAs are added to a folder in contrast to the lines added to a file for sources.list.


Once you're in there type `ls -a` and delete the offending files with `rm filename.list`. Run `sudo apt update` to verify. 
To edit the sources.list file if need be, use `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list'. To save it, press ctrl + O then enter, then ctrl + X to exit `nano`. Run `sudo apt update` to verify. Where did you add those repositories from? I'm curious, I've haven't seen something like this.

Comment: @avisitoritseems Thanks a lot but after running `rm [filename.list]` I am left with only one error `Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu bionic Release                                                                              
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
` The rest goes fine.

Comment: @avisitoritseems  tried to view `sources.list` file and there are lines with `bionic` and `bionic-updates` and `bionic-backports` Shall I comment them?

Comment: Leave the defaults in. `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic` -> main restricted / universe / multiverse / security are all default repos (don't format them like that btw, leave them as is). I can't recall exactly which are default but You can probably find that from the website you downloaded your Ubuntu flavor from.